# Spring Hibernate Validation @RequestBody

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, spring-boot

Using Spring Boot 1.4 and Spring Data Rest/MVC I'm unable to get @Valid @RequestBody working. I have tried multiple versions of Hibernate Validator, declaring Validtor beans etc. No luck.

```
@BasePathAwareController
@RestController
public class TestRestController extends BaseController {
    @PostMapping("/pojo/save")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> upload(@Valid @RequestBody MyPojo pojo) {
     // Code here calling a repository.save. 
}
```

MyPojo contains various validation annotations i.e. @Digits, @NotNull, etc. I actually see the validator exception when the repostiory.save method is called but Spring is not attempting any validation on the pojo.

Here is the section of my POM including the spring dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. I've done a ton of searching and tried many different configurations without any luck.

**Update**

When attempting to save the entity to the database, that's when the validation errors occur. I receive the following error:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='numeric value out of bounds (<9 digits>.<3 digits> expected)...
```

Comment: Change `@RequestBody` to `@ModelAttribute` if you are using Spring form in front end...show the front end code(how u calling this request) if possible

Comment: It's a REST endpoint, so I'm just doing a POST with a JSON object in the body using the Postman Client.

Comment: [this](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/09/request-body-validation-in-spring-mvc-3.2.html) and [this link](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-31-valid-requestbody) may help you

Comment: I found both of those links previously and tried those solutions. I've also tried different versions of hibernate validator and the validation api libraries to no avail. Spring refuses to validate the request body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that the @BasePathAwareController is what's causing the binding validation to not run. Not sure if this is intended behavior or a bug, but by removing that annotation from my controller, the validation runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Valid annotation you should declare BindingResult parameter right after validated pojo. That BindingResult is gonna contain all validation errors and you are free to do whatever you want with them.

Comment: More context: [Getting Started - Validating Form Input](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/). The getting started talks about doing form validation but you could just as well do your own custom response based on a JSON request.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've tried that as well without any luck. BindingResult always contains zero errors. I've also tried creating a @ContainerAdvice class to handle MethodArgumentNotValidException and ConstraintViolationException globally, and that hasn't worked either.

Comment: Try to remove @RequestBody annotation from your parameter and make sure that you have implementations of javax.validation in your classpath, e.g. hibernate validator.
And where did you place BindingResult? It is gonna be right after validated param, like this: `(@Valid MyPojo pojo, BindingResult errors, @Valid MyAnotherPojo anotherPojo, BindingResult anotherErrors)`

Comment: I tried removing the @RequestBody annotation and still no luck. I'm debug logging the result object and this is what I get: in save::pojo: MyPojo{id=null}, result: []. My method signature is save(@Valid MyPojo pojo, BindingResult result)

Comment: What? Do you mean, you are adding BindingResult to your repository method?!
You should add it to your controller method

Comment: It is in my controller method. This is my controller method. public ResponseEntity<?> upload(@Valid @RequestBody MyPojo pojo, BindingResult result) {...}